# Bibliography style which sorts by year irrespective of authors, numerical citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing, sorting

I'm looking for a BST style where all entries will be sorted by year, irrespective of authors, and would produce numerical citations, e.g. for the bibliography list

> [1] Smith, ..., 2000
>
> [2] Smith & Jones, 2000
>
> [3] Smith, ..., 2001
>
> [4] Smith & Tuttle, 2001

The formatting doesn't have to be exactly as in the MWE but citations should be numerical and author names abbreviated.

The `ieeetr` style sorts by author first then date, e.g.

> [1] Smith, ..., 2000
>
> [2] Smith, ..., 2001
>
> [3] Smith & Jones, 2000
>
> [4] Smith & Tuttle 2001

Which isn't what I'm after.

The `chronological.bst` style sorts by year by doesn't provide numerical citations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You mention searching for a bib style file that would implement a particular sorting style, yet you've also set the `biblatex` tag. Now, `biblatex` does not use bst files, at all. Hence, please clarify what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, point taken. I'm after a bst style file for bibtex. Won't be using biblatex.

Answer (score 0):

Nelson Beebe collected an amazing amount of articles about bibliographies and a comprehensive (c. 2007) list of BibTeX style files. Please check out [https://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/bibliographies.html](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ebeebe/bibliographies.html). You will have to do your own digging among the `.bst` files to see what they provide.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.